# Behavior of a gravitation field of an object falling into a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, observers, event-horizon

A thought experiment:

- Take an object that is massive enough so we can detect it's position in space by measuring its gravitation field (for example, by sending almost tangential laser beams and measure how they deviate in the object's gravitation field).
- Take a simple (non-rotating, non-charged) black hole.
- Send this object to the black hole.
- While the object falls into the black hole, measure the object's gravitation field (therefore, the object's position).

I'm wondering what will we see when the object:

- Is getting closer to the event horizon.
- Crossing the event horizon.
- Fails to the singularity under the event horizon.

My intuition tells me following:

- As time around the black hole slows down for an external observer, we may see that the object (i.e. its gravitation field) is always in the place it *touched* the black hole. **(EDIT: According to "[Can you have a giraffe shaped black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/332456/)", this will not happen.)**
- If my previous assumption is wrong, we may *see* how the object falls down to the singularity *behind* the event horizon. Also, the shape of the event horizon will deviate from an ideal sphere and by measuring these deviations we will see a position of the object under the horizon, which seems to contradict to the definition of the event horizon.

My questions are:

- In any generally recognized theory that describes this situation?
- What will happen to the object and its gravitation field according to this theory (theories)?
- How confident we can be in the description given by this theory?

Comment: 'We' are situated where?

Comment: `We` are outside of the black hole.