# Visualization of object falling into black hole from the perspective of a distant observer

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, time-dilation, visualization

There exist a few relativistic renderings, even videos of this kind of event *from the perspective of the infalling object*, yet I have never seen the same event from the perspective of a distant observer, with time/space dilation and possibly redshift and other effects modelled in.

Objects getting close to the event horizon are said to 'freeze' from the perspective of a distant observer, it would be nice to see a video of this, are you aware of any?

**Edit:**

After finding this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/332510/236187

I created this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CwnWDjLh1c

Comment: There are not many, comparatively. You might like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mquEWFutlbs

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick written description.

Let's say we throw into a black hole a clock tied to a flashlight. as the pair comes closer to the event horizon, the hands on the clock appear to us to slow down and the light from the flashlight reddens in color and grows dim. the closer they get to the EH, the slower the hands move, and the redder and dimmer the flashlight becomes. at some point when they are an infinitesimal distance from the EH, the hands appear to stop moving altogether and the whole shebang becomes too dim to make out anymore. To us, the clock and flashlight never appear to "pop through" the EH, they just freeze and fade into invisibility.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, see my updated question and this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/332510/236187

Comment: Deleted my remark. @2080, thanks for the link.